# how to display json data in jquery auto complete textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have php file which generate following json data

```
["Health Infoway","Canada Health Infoway","Infowiki","Info",......"Canada"]
```

I am getting problem to load autocomplete text box using above data.

bellow is my jquery sript which call getorgname.php to get the above data

```
$("input[name=profileOrg]").keyup(function(){

    $( "input[name=profileOrg]" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php','user=' + $('#hiddenUser').val(), function(data){
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return item;
        }));



            }
        }
    }); });
```

Following is my getorgname.php file which generate json data

```
    $User = DekiUser::getCurrent();
 if($User->isAnonymous() || $User->getUserName() != $_REQUEST['user'])
 {
      scriptError("Inappropriate access");  
 }else{
    $ds = my_ldap_connect(CHI_LDAP_LOCATION, CHI_LDAP_PORT, CHI_LDAP_USE_TLS);
    $groups = get_all_groups($ds, CHI_LDAP_BASE_DN, CHI_LDAP_BIND_DIRECTORY, CHI_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD);
    $sr = @ldap_search($ds, "ou=people,".CHI_LDAP_BASE_DN, "(uid=*)");
    $nt = ldap_get_entries( $ds, $sr );

    foreach( $nt as $each )
    {
        if( is_array( $each ) )
        {
            $json[] = $each['o'][0];

        }
    }

}

echo json_encode( $json );
```

I am using following jquery file for auto complete text box

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="CHI_custom/customScripts/jquery.formwizard-3.0.5/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CHI_custom/customScripts/jquery.formwizard-3.0.5/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

How can i display those json data in my auto complete text box

Comment: Have you considered http://twitter.github.com/typeahead.js/ ? Its a new jquery plugin from twitter.

Comment: doesn't the autocomplete function also handle the keyup. I think you may not need the first on key up event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code something like below :

```
$.getJSON('CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php','user=' + $('#hiddenUser').val(), function(data){
    $("input[name=profileOrg]").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

and there is no need to wrap this code in keyup event. So remove that one.

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Here is my solution but it is not done yet. This solutions give me the whole list of the name but i want when the user type anything the list sort according to that. Right now it just display long list without sorting.

    $( "input[name=profileOrg]" ).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response){
       $.getJSON('CHI_custom/customScripts/getorgname.php', 'user=' + $('#hiddenUser').val(), function(data){
        response($.map(data,function(item){
         return item
        }))       
       });
      }
    });